# js how to prevent hiding / catching errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

The problem is that some errors and warnings are not displayed in the console at all. Even banal syntax errors when you call a function on a non-existent variable. I have a suspicion that it is one of the included libs that affects the error output. here are some of those who I think might have been involved:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^41.1.0",
"@xbs/webix-pro": "^10.2.4",
"backbone": "^1.6.0",
"dexie": "^3.2.4",
"webix-backbone": "^1.0.1"
```

Fortunately, while I was writing this question I found a solution, but since there are no answers to this question at all:

- perhaps there is a standard / an universal solution
- for someone it will be useful what I found

Comment: "*I have a suspicion that it is one of the included libs*" - then you'll need to tell us what libraries you are using.

Comment: Which environment does your code run in? Browsers, node.js, something else? Usually unhandled promise rejections should still get logged (unless you are using ancient promise libraries/runtimes).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly in my case was wrong set of error handlers filter. In fact, this is not a library problem, it’s copy-paste that I inherited

```
.then(() => {...})
.catch('DatabaseClosedError', e => {console.log(e) || location.reload();})
.catch(Dexie.INVALID_STATE_ERR, e => {console.log(e) || location.reload();});
```

solved by replacing both for

```
.catch(e => console.error(e) || window.location.reload());
```

at the same time in all places like:

```
webix.require("/js/foo.js?vers=" + v)
  .catch(e => console.error(e)); // explicitly specified error handling
```

Comment: The standard `.catch()` does take only a single argument - were you (at some point) using a different promise library, e.g. Bluebird?

Comment: @Bergi here you can see Dexie, also the reason was in Webix